# How to access computer content using mac address?

Tags: networking

I am making a project in which any one can have video on her pc and access it from anywhere also he can give access to another user so they can watch videos . But the problem is that how to uniquely identify computer on this kind of system .I cant use ip address because it changes after some time only option which i left is mac address but i don't know whether it is possible to access a computer using mac address Or i can use any another way to    do this ?

Comment: Please tell where i am wrong

Comment: You should probably research networking basics. MAC addresses are strictly a Layer 2 phenomenon, and are useless once traffic passes through any typeof Layer 3 device (like a router).

Comment: @EEAA how can i do my project because i think i can't use ipaddress

Comment: I can change my MAC address too, just so you know.  For that matter, my home PC has at least 7 MAC addresses... and I can change all of them if the mood strikes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to share across a network, you need an IP. Simply put. When you wish to share videos to another person for that person to access, you need to invoke either the TCP or UDP protocol for download/stream.

It is not possible to access content purely on the MAC as Layer 2 has limitations that Layer 3 (IP) provides in terms of transferring and establishing communications through ports/sockets.

You have 3 options:

1. You can use the IP and change them, when they are changed (assuming they are dynamic IPs)
2. You can assign each computer static IPs so that they do not change
3. You could use hostnames if you are both on a local network.

Relying purely on MAC isn't sufficient.

Note: If you are both on separate networks and use the internet to communicate, you can use Dynamic-DNS to constantly map you both together, even if the IP changes.

Hope this clears this issue up for you.